# KMT derivation of $PV = \dfrac {1}{3} N m u^2 $

Tags: kinetic-theory

In this derivation there is a step where one incorporates the change in momentum as the particle hits the container. If the initial direction is taken as the positive direction, then the change in momentum would be negative ($-2mu$). However every derivation I have found ignores the negative sign. I believe what one chooses as the positive direction is arbitrary, but should not the derivation also work if this particular sign convention is reversed? If one does propagate the negative sign it looks like the final equation would indeed have the negative sign (which does not make sense?). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The change in momentum of the particle due to it hitting a wall is negative.
Thus the force on the particle due to the wall is negative - Newton's second law.
So the force on the wall due to the particle is positive - Newton's third law.